# Adding CSS file to a master page - illegal characters in path?

Tags: visual-studio, css, custom-masterpage

I'm making a custom master page with a custom CSS file, being deployed in a feature form VS2010. I'm using the CssRegistation control to add the new CSS, but whenever I try to load a page that uses it, I get an "Illegal characters in path" exception. Which is odd, because there aren't any illegal characters that I can see in the path.

The code I'm using to add the CSS to the page looks like this (from MSDN):

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/myfolder/mystyle.css %>"  After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

I've check the relevant galleries and the master page is deploying correctly to _layouts/masterpage/mymaster.master, and the CSS is deploying correctly to Style Library/myfolder/mystyle.css.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. The error was coming from an old CssRegistration control that I hadn't commented out properly...

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing "Style Library" to "Style%20Library"?

Comment: Doesn't work - '%' is an illegal character when explicitly declared in the path.

Comment: Shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

According to this blog post, you will have that issue if you are using SharePoint Foundation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2010/04/09/working-with-the-sharepoint-theming-engine.aspx.  In SPF you need to hard code the URL.

Comment: Yes that's right. The <% $SPUrl ~sitecollection token is part of the Publishing Infrastructure which is not available in SharePoint Foundation. But did @Moray mention that he/she is using foundation?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint Standard.